# Is this WFS 2.0.0 specification example using a namespaced id attribute correct?

Tags: c#, wfs

I am building c# models for the WFS spec, specifically the Filter in the fes namespace.  The spec contains the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<fes:Filter
   xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0"
   xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0
   http://schemas.opengis.net/filter/2.0/filterAll.xsd
   http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2
   http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd">
   <fes:Overlaps>
      <fes:ValueReference>Geometry</fes:ValueReference>
      <gml:Polygon gml:id="P1" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326">
         <gml:exterior>
            <gml:LinearRing>
               <gml:posList>10 10 20 20 30 30 40 40 10 10</gml:posList>
            </gml:LinearRing>
         </gml:exterior>
      </gml:Polygon>
   </fes:Overlaps>
</fes:Filter>
```

Notice the "id" on the gml:Polygon is actually "gml:id" and not "id".  I can understand that attributes can be namespaced but since the Polygon is already in the "gml" namespace is this still correct?  Perhaps it is just a redundancy?

I only ask because when I deserialize I lose this value and therefore when I serialize the model I get this:

```
<Filter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0&#xA;   http://schemas.opengis.net/filter/2.0/filterAll.xsd&#xA;   http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2&#xA;   http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0">
  <Overlaps>
    <ValueReference>Geometry</ValueReference>
    <Polygon srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2">
      <exterior>
        <LinearRing>
          <posList>10 10 20 20 30 30 40 40 10 10</posList>
        </LinearRing>
      </exterior>
    </Polygon>
  </Overlaps>
</Filter>
```

So is the example correct and my deserializer not reading it an error or is the example incorrect?  My model is defined like this:

```
[XmlRoot("Polygon", Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2")]
public class Polygon
{

    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("srsName")]
    public string SrsName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("exterior")]
    public Exterior Exterior { get; set; }
}
```

I assume the "Id" is in the same namespace as the Polygon class (gml).

UPDATE: thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666023/xml-attribute-not-getting-namespace-prefix I learned that I can set "Form" on the XmlAttribute:

```
    [XmlAttribute("id", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
```

Unfortunately this now requires that the prefix be present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gml:id is required because no default namespace is declared in

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<fes:Filter
   xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0"
   xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0
   http://schemas.opengis.net/filter/2.0/filterAll.xsd
   http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2
   http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd">
```

If instead you had:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<fes:Filter
   xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
   xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0"
   xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0
   http://schemas.opengis.net/filter/2.0/filterAll.xsd
   http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2
   http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd">
```

You would be allowed

```
<gml:Polygon id="P1" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326">
```

and indeed

```
<Polygon id="P1" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326">
```

Comment: The attribute namespace defaults to the document namespace and not the namespace of the containing node.  If they are both in the same namespace and neither is the default then the both must be explicitly prefixed.